# Payment through online banking in android

Tags: android, payment

I am in need to develop an android application which facilitate payment or money transfer to another user account using online banking service.

Is there any api available in android for online banking ?

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks!

Comment: check this http://www.zooz.com/

Answer (score -3):

What I have done is implementing the same payment gateway which I used in my websites.We can use those gateways in Android Webviews.So if you are currently using any getways just proceed with the same.Otherwise go for some mobile gateways mentioned [here](http://www.indiafocus.in/internet/paymentgateway/mobile/)